# Valid/invalid bit associated with memory segments

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, memory-segmentation

From "Operating System Concepts":

**Segmentation** (*without virtual memory*)

> With each entry in segment table associate:
>
> - validation bit = 0 -> illegal segment

I understood that the valid/invalid bit is useful dealing with pages (a process doesn't use all the pages provided by the hardware architecture, so only the process' pages have to be marked as valid), but why is a valid/invalid bit associated with every entry in a segment table? Isn't the number of segments known at compile time? Every process' segment should be marked as valid, or not?

Comment: What happens when the process wants to deallocate the segment? Is it removed from the segment table, or is the valid bit cleared?

Comment: Also, the number of segments won't necessarily be known at compile time. Programs can potentially modify themselves and can ask the OS for more memory during runtime.

Comment: You are facing several problems her. (1) It looks like you have a $@#$y book. (2) text books invent things for teaching purposes. In Intel-land (the only place that widely used segments) there is a PRESENT bit. I've never heard of a "validation bit" Maybe some systems have one but this looks like  teaching invention.

https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/s05_01.htm

(3) Segments are finally dying the death they should have received 30 years ago. By the time you graduate, you're not likely to encounter them.